# sed used to replace text between some chars with new text

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a question with I can't figure out.

I have in xml file something like this:

```
<tag desc="some desc can be different" dep="dep" >value</tag>
```

I wanna change this like using sed to:

```
<tag desc="NEW DESC" dep="dep" >value</tag>
```

My question is: can I use sed to replace text between "`<tag ... >`" with new one?

Thank you for help :)

Comment: XML and HTML are *not* regular languages.  As such, trying to work some magic with RE tools like `sed` to parse HTML may be a recipe for disaster.

Comment: You sure can, but keep in mind that [regexes are not for parsing (X)HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1807643).

Answer (score 4):

Since you are not trying to really parse the xml sed can help you:

```
sed -i 's/\(<tag[^>]*[ ]*desc[ ]*\)=[ ]*"[^"]*"/\1="NEW DESC"/g' input.xml
```

But if you want to have a robust solution, use `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet edit -L -u "//tag/@desc" -v "NEW DESC" input.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for quick answer :)

I have done something like this:

```
typeset repTagdesc='desc="NEW DESC" dep="dep"'
sed -i "s&\(<tag\).*\(>.[0-9]\)&\1 ${repTagdesc}\2&" input.xml
```

Is this solution OK? I am not familiar with sed, thats why I am asking.
I check it and its works for:

```
<tag>10</tag>
<tag desc="some desc" dep="dep">20</tag>
<tag desc="other desc" dep="dep">30</tag>
```